# sending an email address with axios within Vue.Js component to a laravel backend is failing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to make a vue component that checks if a given input is available or not in the database. The calls to the server i am doing with axios inside the vue component. for some reason, when i type the `@` symbol in the email, it breaks.here is my code so far:

this is the backend.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function verifyName($name){

        if (request()->wantsJson()){

            $names=User::where('name', $name)->count();
            if ($names>0)
                return 1;
            if ($names==0)
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public function verifyEmail($email){

        if (request()->wantsJson()){
            $emails=User::where('email', $email)->count();
            if ($emails>0)
                return 1;
            if ($emails==0)
                return 0;
        }
    }


}
```

here is the vue script:

```
<script>
    export default {

        data(){
            return{
                name: '',
                email: '',
                nameTaken: false,
                emailTaken: false,
                nameAvailable:false,
                emailAvailable:false,
                nameIsTooShort:false

            }
        },
        methods:{
            verifyName(){
                axios.get('/verify/'+this.name)
                     .then((response) => {
                       if (response.data){
                           this.nameTaken=true;
                           this.nameAvailable=false
                       }
                       if(!response.data){
                           this.nameTaken = false;
                           this.nameAvailable=true
                       }
                    });
            },

            verifyEmail(){
                axios.get('/verify/'+this.email)
                    .then((response) => {
                        if (response.data){
                            this.emailTaken=true;
                            this.emailAvailable=false

                        }
                        if(!response.data){
                            this.emailTaken = false;
                            this.emailAvailable=true
                        }
                    });
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

and here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/verify/{name}','TestController@verifyName');
Route::get('/verify/{email}','TestController@verifyEmail');
```

and here is a small gif to show it.

[image: here is a gif to show what i am facing]

as requested, here is the html part where i show the message.

```
   <div class="field-body">
    <div class="field">
           <p class="control">
          <input class="input" id="email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" v-model="email"  @change="verifyEmail">
         <div class="help is-danger" v-show="emailTaken" v-cloak>This e mail is taken</div>
        <div class="help is-success" v-show="emailAvailable" v-cloak>Great. this email is available</div>
     </p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the html section where the message gets shown?

Comment: can you send that as **POST** because probably get will urlencode the **@** in the **GET**

Comment: And you can check with form request rules is much better using Unique

Comment: @RossWilson i added it to the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using laravel's validator instead.

One way to go about it, in your "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController"

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; 

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'              => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'email'             => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        'password'          => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Make note of the `unique:xxxxx` rule  where `xxxxx` is your table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

If the email or name is not unique the validator will return the error response. So you would use it at the beginning of your register function.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    // rest of registration routine here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its happens because of you are using "@" symbol in url string. This is reserved character. ([Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid))
Solution: send email to verification on server in json body of post request.